# std::condition_variable::wait in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am slightly confused in mutex, lock, and wait.

Here is my code:

```
void producer(std::mutex* m, std::condition_variable* cv,bool* signal) {

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    m->lock();
    *signal = true;
    m->unlock();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    cv->notify_one();

    printf("notify one\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
}

void consumer(std::mutex*m, std::condition_variable* cv, bool* signal, int index) {

    if(index == 2) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);

    cv->wait(lk, [&] { return (*signal); });

    printf("consumer %d passes this point!\n", index);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
}

int main() {
    
    bool signal = false;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread th1(producer, &m, &cv, &signal);
    std::thread th2(consumer, &m, &cv, &signal, 1);
    std::thread th3(consumer, &m, &cv, &signal, 2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

`std::this_thread::sleep_for` is added to explain my question.
There are producer, consumer1, and consumer 2. I think that this code should work as follows:

1. consumer1 meets `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);` so it locks.
2. consumer1 meets `cv->wait`. Because initial value of `signal` is `false`, consumer1 is blocked and the lock is released.
3. producer meets `m->lock();`, `*signal = true;`, `m->unlock();`, and `sleep_for`. Therefore, `signal` becomes `true`.
4. consumer2 meets `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);` and `cv->wait(lk, [&] { return (*signal); });`. Becuase `signal` is `true`, this thread just passes it. So, `printf("consumer %d passes this point!\n", index);` is executed.
5. producer meets `cv->notify_one();`. consumer 1 is unblocked and check the condition. Because `signal` is `ture`, consumer1 can pass this point. Therefore, consumer1 meets `printf`.

Consequently, my expected result is

```
consumer 2 passes this point!
notify one
consumer 1 passes this point!
```

However, the real result is

```
consumer 2 passes this point!
notify one
```

It seems to be that consumer1 cannot pass `cv->wait(lk, [&] { return (*signal); });`, even though `notify_one()` is called and the condition is satisfied. Is there anything wrong in my understanding?

Comment: you are using `.join()` so your code is running synchronously. ie. producer completes, only then does consumer 1 complete. If you use `.detach()` your code will run as expected (non blocking, asynchronous) (apart from the main thread exiting so add another condition variable or put it to sleep.

Comment: As a really simple rule of thumb, never sleep while you hold a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is consumer 2 doesn't release the lock on the mutex before going to sleep:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);

cv->wait(lk, [&] { return (*signal); });

printf("consumer %d passes this point!\n", index);   // <-- mutex is still locked here
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
```

So even though the condition in consumer 1 may be satisfied, it cannot acquire the lock on the mutex because it's already locked by another thread.

An [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) gives you more fine grained control than its counterpart [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) including the ability to unlock. What you can do is add an unlock call before the consumer goes to sleep like this:

```
...
lk.unlock();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
```

Otherwise the lock on the mutex is only released after consumer 2 has completed executing the `consumer()` function, i.e. after the long sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You are not releasing lock in `consumer` routine.
The code below does what is expected:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

void producer(std::mutex* m, std::condition_variable* cv,bool* signal) {

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);
        *signal = true;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    cv->notify_all();

    printf("notify one\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}

void consumer(std::mutex*m, std::condition_variable* cv, bool* signal, int index) {

    if(index == 2) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);
        cv->wait(lk, [&] { return (*signal); });
    }

    printf("consumer %d passes this point!\n", index);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}

int main() {

    bool signal = false;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread th1(producer, &m, &cv, &signal);
    std::thread th2(consumer, &m, &cv, &signal, 1);
    std::thread th3(consumer, &m, &cv, &signal, 2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Note the enclosing brackets around `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(*m);` to provide a local scope.